# Excel - Want to populate a cell based information in another cell (multiple answers trigger same output)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to populate a cell in Excel (2016-WIN) based on the information in another cell. I am currently doing this using

`=IF(C27="James","Dog",IF(C27="Paul","Cat"))` and so on.  This works very well for me in a one-to-one dependency scenario as I currently have.

However, I am now trying to populate a cell based on information in another cell where multiple answers in the original cell will trigger the same output in the target cell.  For example:

`IF C27 = "Bill" or "John" or "Kate" or "Joan"` then enter "Orange" in the target cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IF(OR) formula.

```
    =IF(OR(C1="Bill",C1="John",C1="Kate"),"ORANGE","green")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly-thank you!